# angularjs - Trouble getting data from database within template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a blog like structured web app In AngularJS. Im trying to retrieve the user which is an other of a post and retrieve their display name dynamically as it loops through all the posts but I cant seem to retrieve data correctly.. This is what I have done so far.

Blog Controller:

```
uno.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, $http, adbFactory){
    $scope.derp = 'derp!!!!!';
    adbFactory.get($http, 'get users 1', false).success(function(data){
        $scope.user = data;
    }).error(function(){
        console.log('Errorrr');
    });

    $scope.init = function(){
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get all blog_posts', true).success(function(data){
            $scope.posts = data;
            console.log($scope.posts);
        });
    };

    $scope.getAuthor = function(_id) {
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get users id ' +_id+ ' spec', false).success(function(data){
            //$scope.author = data;
            //console.log($scope.author);
            return data;
        });
    };
});
```

If I console.log the data it shows the users perfectly given the author id which is in the database, but when i attempt to call the getAuthor function using the '{{ }}' scope i get a collage of errors... heres my blog template below.

Blog Template:

```
<div class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-repeat="topic in posts" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div id="news-post" class="panel animated fadeInUp">
                <div class="row" ng-init="getAuthor(topic.author_id)">
                    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns"> 
                        <img src="{{ topic['thumb'] }}" alt="" style="border-radius:50%; height:100px; width: 150px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="left large-10 small-10 columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#/news/post/{{ topic['id'] }}">{{topic['title']}}</a> <p>Posted By, {{ getAuthor(topic.author_id).email }}</p></h2>
                            <p>{{ topic['body'] }}</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

not quite sure what the problem can be.. Any thing I'm missing?

UPDATE::
I recently updated my controller and factories to get a better scope of handling my data flow, my Controller now looks like this:

```
uno.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, $http, adbFactory, $cacheFactory, unoFunctions){
    $scope.init = function(){
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get all blog_posts', true).success(function(data){
            $scope.posts = data;

            $scope.getUser = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
                //console.log($scope.userData);

                return $scope.userData;
            };
        });

        $scope.getTags = function(_id) {
            var post = unoFunctions.getPost(_id);
            var _tags = post.tags.split(',');
            for(var i = 0; i < _tags.length; i++)
            {
                _tags[i] = _tags[i].trim();
            }

            return _tags;
        };

        $scope.getUserName = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
            return $scope.userData.display_name;
        };

        $scope.getUser = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
            //console.log($scope.userData);
            return $scope.userData;
        };

        $scope.getUserName = function(_id) {
            $scope.userData = unoFunctions.getUser(_id);
            return $scope.userData.display_name;
        };
    };
});
```

the unoFunctions factory is wht I use now to handle certain requests from my database, and that is shown below.

uno.factory('unoFunctions', function(adbFactory, $http, $cacheFactory){
    var fact = {};

```
var user = $cacheFactory('user');
var post = $cacheFactory('post');

fact.getUser = function(_id) {
    if(!user.get(_id)){
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get users id '+_id+' spec', false).success(function(data){
            user.put(_id, data);
        });
    }

    return user.get(_id);
};
fact.getPost = function(_id) {
    if(!post.get(_id))
    {
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get blog_posts id '+_id+' spec', false).success(function(data){
            post.put(_id, data);
        });
    }

    return post.get(_id);
};

fact.loggedIn = function()
{
    console.log('gfdg');
};

/*------------------------------*/
return fact;
```

});

And my template to output the result is this:

```
<div class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-repeat="topic in posts | filter:postTitle | orderBy:'-time' " style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div id="news-post" class="panel animated fadeInUp" ng-init="getTags(topic.id)">
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns">
                        <img src="{{ topic['thumb'] }}" alt="" style="border-radius:50%; height:120px; width: 200px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="left large-10 small-10 columns">
                        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                            <h2 class="post-title">
                            <a href="#/news/post/{{ topic['id'] }}">
                            {{topic['title']}} 
                            </a> 
                            <p style="font-size:13px; font-style:italic; color:#a5a5a5" class="right">{{ topic.time | timeago }} {{  }}</p>
                            <p style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; color:#aaa">Posted By, {{ getUser(topic.author_id).display_name }}</p></h2>
                            <p>{{ topic['body'] }}</p> 
                            <div ng-repeat="tag in getTags(topic.id)"><span style="background:#ccc; margin:7px; padding:4px; border-radius:5px; font-size:12px" class="left">{{ tag }}</span></div>
                            <p class="right" style="background:#dedede; font-size:13px; padding:7px; border-radius:6px; color:#1985A1;">{{ topic.category }}</p
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine and returns the required results I'm looking for but I wish to get rid of the countless Error: `[$rootScope:infdig]` errors and keep my console clean.. I researched the error and it seems to be because when I call functions from the unoFunctions factory like, getUser, or getPost. it returns a new array each time or something like that which I guess throws things out of scope. I'm not entirely sure, and reason for this?

Comment: what's your data? the structure of your data?

Comment: Its ins JSON Format. Like an array

Comment: Your question is not clear. what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This binding

```
<p>Posted By, {{ getAuthor(topic.author_id).email }}</p>
```

assumes that `getAuthor` returns an object, but it doesn't, even with proper `return` statement - because asynchronous request takes place, and `adbFactory` chain will apparently return a promise, not an object. And doing `adbFactory.get` every time `getAuthor` bindings are being watched would be bad performance-wise - json result has to be parsed constantly, even with `$http` cache.

A suitable solution for caching and binding service results to the scope (and a precursor to full-blown model) is

```
var authors = $cacheFactory('authors');
$scope.getAuthor = function(_id) {
    if (!authors.get(_id)) {
        authors.put(_id, {});
        adbFactory.get($http, 'get users id ' +_id+ ' spec', false).success(function(data){
            authors.put(_id, data);
        });
    }

    return authors.get(_id);
};
```

Comment: but then wht is the cache factory?

Comment: A built-in service that provides application-wide data storage https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory , inject it into the controller.

Comment: would it be best to use? wht if the cache is cleared?

Comment: Yes, it is a good option, you can store data objects from requests by your own, but $cacheFactory keeps you from reinventing the wheel. You have full control over the cache, it won't be cleared unless you want it to.

Comment: Im now getting a Error: [$rootScope:infdig]  error, from creaating a new array of objects from everything the getAuthor is called in a loop, anyway to get beside that?

Comment: It is impossible to say without seeing how exactly you do that.